# Zend Framework 3 - Meta tags weirdly escaped - impact on canonical url?

Tags: escaping, seo, meta-tags, zend-framework3, canonical-link

I got the following source code generated by Zend Framework 3 HeadMeta view helper:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE&#x3D;edge">
```

Example code: `<?php echo $this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=edge'); ?>`.

Happens also with links using HeadLink view helper:

```
<link href="&#x2F;vendor&#x2F;flag-icon-css&#x2F;css&#x2F;flag-icon.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text&#x2F;css">
<link href="&#x2F;vendor&#x2F;bootstrap-select&#x2F;dist&#x2F;css&#x2F;bootstrap-select.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text&#x2F;css">
<link href="&#x2F;artist&#x2F;franz-ackermann" rel="canonical">
```

Example code: `<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/styles.css', 'all'); ?>`.

Why the meta tags are escaped in that extreme way? I compared with other pages such as wikipedia and noticed that they are using just plain readable characters (not the unicode pendants for slashes, equal-signs etc.).

How can I turn it off? Does the escaping of the canonical url has an impact in how the urls are getting processed / display by Google? Or does Google understand the escaped variants?

Comment: Please have a read of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is no way to reproduce this using defaults, as by default this things work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I thought it is trivial, therefore I did not include sample code. However, I added two lines of example code as you suggested.

Comment: Hmmm ok, that's the right way to do it. How are you rendering your views? Do you call a render action in a controller and then return that? Could you provide complete copy paste of a controller action on which this happens?

Comment: Nope, just call the code statements within a view script. Therefore everything completely normal. I digged into the code (zend-view) and found the line @Lost Packet mentioned in his/her answer. So I conclude this is normal behavior. Therefore I accepted his answer. But why is this normal behavior? Why does the code gets escaped that much?

Comment: Code gets escaped once, it seems that in your case it gets escaped more often. Give it a check by downloading the [Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) and dumping some data in the provided `indexAction`, you'll see that it functions perfectly normal. The issue is somewhere in your project, the trick is finding out where.

Comment: Tested vanilla Skeleton Application - same behavior. F.e. `<link href="&#x2F;css&#x2F;style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text&#x2F;css">
<link href="&#x2F;img&#x2F;favicon.ico" rel="shortcut&#x20;icon" type="image&#x2F;vnd.microsoft.icon">` (copied from source code). Therefore works as vanilla sekelton application - so everything seems to be ok.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a server configuration to handle this? I literally re-installed a fresh skeleton download 2 days ago for a new project and did not encounter this behaviour. Neither do I see it in the many, many projects I maintain currently, pretty much all of them ZF3 (few plain php ones).

Comment: Yes. I used the php "webserver" (`php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php`). Tested source code in Chrome and Safari, same behavior. In my production environment I run nginx of course. Therefore the problem seems unlikely to come from the internal php-server / nginx.

Comment: @rkeet - Are you looking in Chrome dev tools, because you won't see the issue there.  You have to right click and View Page Source instead of using Inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view helper uses escapeAttribute() helper to escape output.

Might look a little odd to read but will work just fine.